# Is it possible to have an output shape like 512x3x3 in caffe for a Fully connected layer

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I have been reading [this paper](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~honglak/nips2016-perspectiveTransformer.pdf) and I have seen that they used a fully connected layer with dimensions 1x1x1024 and then in the next step they suddenly have 512x3x3x3. How is that possible? How would you do that in caffe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the code belonging to the paper.
What they do is to reshape the layer after the fully connected layer like this:

```
voxel_dec:add(nn.Linear(opt.nz, 3*3*3*512))
voxel_dec:add(nn.ReLU())
voxel_dec:add(nn.Reshape(512, 3, 3, 3))
```

Comment: If this is the correct answer to your question, then please accept the answer to indicate it for future visitors.

Comment: Yeah, I can only do that in two days cause it is my own question @KevinKatzke

Comment: True, I forgot that :)